# How to safely use dm-crypt as overlayfs uper partition?

Tags: key-management, physical-access, dm-crypt

### Context

I'm working to make an embedded devices safe against physical access. (publicly accessible device and can be easily stolen)

I already made the following action :

- secure boot is enabled on cpu, bootloaded is signed
- Image is also signed and verified at boot
- the base rootfs is protected against modification by dm-verity. Hash and salt are provided by u-boot with dm-mod.create= option, and stored in a signed file.

With that, i have a safe read-only system (I hope), and I now want to make it writeable only by the device itself.
For that, I want to use a second partition, with dm-crypt on it. Key will be stored in the CPU OTP (fuse) and given by u-boot. This encrypted partition will then be used as the uper layer of an overlayfs, mounted as rootfs.

### My concern

The dm-crypt volume will so contains all device specific information that include sensitive information (access key to remote servers) and /etc directory, including the shadow file.
I consider dm-crypt safe enough to protect against flash extraction to read or edit this information.
But, as this is an overlayfs, clearing the whole uper partition will result in a factory reset. 
Not a big issue at first, but this cause in fact a sort of big issue : the root password is then restored to the factory value (revert to original shadow file) and so the attacker can ssh to the device and read the encryption key. Then it could use it to decrypt the remaining data on the disk. 
I could fill the disk with zero in case the encrypted volume is no more formatted at boot, but the attacker can still copy the encryption key and use it to decrypt a dump of my encrypted volume.

### Actual question(s)

How could I prevent that ? 
Is storing the key in the OTP bad ? Being able to change the key could solve part of issues, but where ?
Could LUKS help me for that ? If so, how ?

### Bonus question

Also, could we imagine that an attacker could delete/zero a region of the encrypted partition (without knowing the key), so that in my overlayfs, only /etc/shadow is back to its original version ? Or does any modification will trigger an error ?

Comment: What are you ultimately concerned about? Remote Access Key being stolen? Maybe store it in hardware instead of software? You are already assuming physical attacks which makes protection harder. How do you think keys would get stolen? If keys/passwords get reset to default values after device reset you could do the reset offline (physical, no ssh, firewall etc) until values have been changed. Depends of course somewhat on how the device is used in practice, who uses it etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, the ultimate goal is to prevent keys from being stolen. Keys are already stored in a dedicated hardware module (NXP SXF1800), but if you don't want the module itself being stolen, you still have to protect the access key to this module.
This is what I want to do by encrypting the device flash memory, that contains the access key to the hardware. But then, you have to secure the encryption key. Putting it in the CPU fuses protect it, as soon the attacker does not find a way to boot the device (by resetting root password)

Comment: "but if you don't want the module itself being stolen, you still have to protect the access key to this module" If you dont want it to be stolen, then you need to physically secure it. However, you already said it is NOT physically secure "(publicly accessible device and can be easily stolen)". If you do that, you could put the access key as well in some hardware token like yubikey/nitrokey and maybe specifically secure that against easy unplugging.